# Integrating dynamics ax with Web API

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

it is possible to integrating Microsoft Dynamics AX with Web API, if its is possible please send how to integrate and what is best way to integrating with Microsoft Dynamics AX (i.e Web API, WCF or any other is best).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean somethins like [AIF](https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/gg731810.aspx)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at the [help] page [ask] to learn how to ask a question that has the best chances to receive an answer here. Your question in its current form is not a good fit for the Q&A format of Stack Overflow (see also what is on topic in [help/on-topic]).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a C# class library, which would act as a wrapper/broker for the WebAPI. You can provide the class library with the URL to the Web API as a Service Reference, which would then discover the webmethods exposed by the API. Once added to the AOT, you would be able to access these as strongly typed methods / types.

For a tutorial on how to do this, see the example on adding Bing search:
[Walkthrough: Calling an External Web Service from X++ [AX2012]](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500185.aspx)

Comment: Hi Weezul , what is the best way for calling MS Dynamics AX through External Web Services, Web API or WCF Service ??. Please suggest one..

Comment: Ah, I understand now that you are planning to integrate the other way around, from WebAPI to Ax. Although I have never implemented that myself, I can imagine that AIF (Application Integration Framework) would be your best bet.

This would be a good place to start:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa570087(v=ax.50).aspx